# Compare value from two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two arrays

```
$request_quantity   = ['0' => 15, '1' => 15];
$available_quantity = ['0' => 10, '1' => 10];
```

Now all of `$request_quantity` is more than `$available_quantity`

```
foreach($request_quantity as $request)
{
    foreach($available_quantity as $available )
    {
        if ( $request > $available ) 

        // return to page 'exceeded the maximum qty';
    }
}
```

With this loop it's validate first value only. How do I validate all of them?

Comment: You need to not trigger the error immediately, and store it for evaluation AFTER the nested loops are completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to compare two array element by loop then you can do it by one loop( both array size should be same).

Make an result array to store comparison result of  $request_quantity  each element with $available_quantity each element.

you can try like this:

```
$request_quantity   = ['0' => 15, '1' => 10];
$available_quantity = ['0' => 10, '1' => 15];
$result = array();



for($i=0;$i<count($request_quantity);$i++)
    {
      $result[] = $request_quantity[$i] > $available_quantity[$i] ? 1:0;

    }
print_r($result);
```

[live demo](https://eval.in/111571)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop instead:

```
if (($c = count($request_quantity)) !== count($available_quantity)) {
    echo 'Unequal number of elements';
}

for ($i=0; $i < $c; $i++) { 
    if ($request_quantity[$i] > $available_quantity[$i]) {
        echo 'Exceeded max qty', PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exceeded max qty
Exceeded max qty
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
$request_quantity   = array( 15, 15, 7, 5 );
$available_quantity = array( 10, 10, 12, 3 );
$is_item_available = array();

array_walk( $request_quantity, function ( $value, $key ) {

    global $request_quantity, $available_quantity, $is_item_available;

    if ( $request_quantity[$key] <= $available_quantity[$key] ) {
        $is_item_available[$key] = true;
    } else {
        $is_item_available[$key] = false;
    }

});
```